# python, return calculations with %d

Tags: python

I have a silly question.
I have a def like this:

```
def render_row_number(self):
    return '%d' % next(self.counter)
```

comes from an app, which I cannot change. It counts the row numbers of a table, but starts from 0, instead of 1. So I wondered, could I just add a +1 to it? 
So it would look something like:

```
return '%d' + 1 % next(self.counter)
```

But would be actually working :P

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: First you say you cannot change it, then you ask if you can change it?

Comment: Oh, Rawing. The wording isn't the best, I know. English is not my native language, but luckily guys understood what I meant and it solved now. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add 1 to the number, not to the string.

```
return '%d' % (next(self.counter) + 1)
```